# How to extend a root finding method from 1D to multi dimensions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, vector-calculus

The number (0.25 Pi) is a third order root of f[x] below.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := Sin[x] - Cos[x] - Sqrt[2] (x - 0.25 Pi);
Chop@Normal@Series[f[x], {x, 0.25 Pi, 4}]
```

-0.235702 (-0.785398 + x)^3

Newton's method converges slowly to a multiple root such as the third order root above, but if f[x] is sufficiently well behaved, g[x_]:=If[ f[x]==0, 0, f[x]/f'[x] ] only has simple roots. I can't understand why, but very few books on numerical methods mention that. Anyway we can implement Newton's method to find a root of g[x] above and have quadratic convergence on the root. That can be done as follows:

```
rt=NestList[With[{y=f[#],yp=f'[#]},
If[y==0,#,#+y*yp/(y*f''[#]-yp^2)]]&,
5.0,5]
```

{5.,3.86977,2.28629,0.996825,0.786027,0.785398}

```
0.25 Pi - %
```

{-4.2146, -3.08437, -1.50089, -0.211427, -0.000629266, -7.64783*10^-10}

How do we extend the code above to find a root of a system of nonlinear equations in two or more dimensions? Example given:

```
f[x_,y_]:={Sin[x+y]+Cos[x-y]+x,Sin[x+y]+y-Cos[x-y]};
```

find the root of f[x,y] at  { x-> -0.514933, y-> 0.514933 } .
I know how to find that root with the built-in FindRoot.
I want to know how to extend the method above.

Comment: It is certainly unfortunate that [Schröder's method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroedersMethod.html) is not more well-known; nevertheless, this is more a math question than a *Mathematica* question, no?

Comment: I think I will put a similar question on the stack-exchange math site.

Comment: Really not a Mathematica question. There is a substantial literature on root deflation, though. Macaulay matrices get used in many such, at least in the case of polynomial systems. I should add that in general this is more complicated than the univariate case, because the "multiplicity structure" can be more complicated: in the univariate case multiplicity n implies n-1 derivatives vanish at the root and these provide a basis for what is called the "dual space. Dual to what? I won't get into that. But the idea is that in the multivariate setting things need not be so straightforward.

Comment: As for `f[x]/f'[x]` having simple roots, just factor out the root, that is, write `f` as `f[x] = (x-r)^n*g[x]` where `g does not vanish at the root `r`. Then the quotient is `(x-r) * g/(n*g+(x-r)*g'` and the second factor is simply `1/n` at `x=r`, hence this quotient vanishes to first order.

Answer (score 2):

2D [Schröder's method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroedersMethod.html), which gives the idea how it can be extended to whatever dimensions.  The first step is to construct the derivative tensors `{zz, zp, zpp}` and the iteration step.

```
ff[x_, y_] := {Sin[x + y] + Cos[x - y] + x, 
   Sin[x + y] + y - Cos[x - y]};

{zz, zp, zpp} = NestList[D[#, {{x, y}}] &, ff[x, y], 2];

Block[{LinearSolve, x, y, p}, 
 schroederStep[p : {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] = 
   p - LinearSolve[zp.zp - zpp.zz, zp.zz];
 ]
```

Try it out:

```
root = {x, y} /. FindRoot[ff[x, y] == 0, {x, 0}, {y, 0}];
seq = NestWhile[schroederStep, {0., 0.},
  Norm[Subtract[##]] > 100 $MachineEpsilon &,
  2, 6]
seq - root
(*
  {-0.514933, 0.514933}
  {0., 0.}               <-- cool: no error
*)
```

Verify quadratic convergence:

```
wp = 1000;
root = {x, y} /. 
   FindRoot[ff[x, y] == 0, {x, 0}, {y, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp];
Block[{$MinPrecision = wp, $MaxPrecision = wp},
  seq = NestList[schroederStep, {0, N[1/10, wp]}, 10]
  ];
Log[
   Norm /@ Transpose[Transpose@seq - root]
   ] // Ratios // N
(*
{2.54409, 2.48968, 2.41174, 2.20723, 2.09436,
 2.04506, 2.02203, 2.0109,  2.00542, 2.0027}  <-- approaches 2
*)
```